# Использование View вместо Fragment в ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Сейчас делаю просмоторщик фотографий, и в нем нужно реализовать перелистывание фотографий. Делаю это с помощью ViewPager, но там можно использовать только Fragment, но как использовать там свой View?

**UPD:** Попробовал указанные варианты, все ровно не работает.

Fragment:

```
public class PhotosViewActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new PhotosAdapter());
}

private class PhotosAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(Loader.context).inflate(R.layout.photo_image_view, parent, false); 
        parent.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("PhotoView", "size: " + photos.size());
        return 1;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_view, container, false);
}

public static PhotosViewActivity newInstance(int position) {
    return new PhotosViewActivity();
}
```

}

R.id.photo_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

R.id.photo_image_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: google -> `android viewpager with views`. Ответ по первой ссылке. Стыдно.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределяемый при создании `PagerAdapter` метод `instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, int position)` возвращает в качестве аргумента текущий `View` - `ViewGroup parent`. Вы можете добавить туда свой `View` и вернуть уже "пропатченый" результат.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    View view = views.get (position); // массив View, которые надо добавить в зависимости от страницы пейджера
    parent.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, не работает. Может проблема в том что нельзя открывать несколько фрагментов? Или нет? p.s. обновил свой вопрос, и добавил код